# Dataframe instance management in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I recently worked on a project parsing CSV files with cable modem MAC addresses (CMMAC) data that made it useful to incorporate dataframes through the Pandas module. One of the problems I encountered related to the overall approach to and structure of the dataframes themselves. Specifically I was concerned with having to increment the number of instances of dataframes to perform specific actions on the data. I did not feel that having to invoke "df1", "df2", "df3", etc was an efficient approach to writing in Python.

Below is a segment of the code where I had to instantiate the dataframes for different actions. The sample files (file1.csv and file2.csv) are identical and posted below as well.

file1.csv and file2.csv

```
cmmac,match
AABBCCDDEEFF,true
001122334455,false
001122334455,false
```

Python script:

```
import os
import glob
from functools import partial
import pandas as pd

#read and concatenate all CSV files in working directory
df1 = pd.concat(map(partial(pd.read_csv, header=0), glob.glob(os.path.join('', "*.csv"))))

#sort by column labeled "cmmac"
df2 = df1.sort_values(by='cmmac')

#delete any duplicate records
df3 = df2.drop_duplicates()

#convert MAC address format to colon notation (e.g. 001122334455 to 00:11:22:33:44:55)
df3['cmmac'] = df3['cmmac'].apply(lambda x: ':'.join(x[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(x), 2)))
```

There were additional actions that were performed on the data in the CSV files and by the end I had thirteen dataframes (df13). With more complex projects I would have been in a death spiral of dataframes using this method.

The question I have is: how should dataframes be managed in order to avoid using this many instances? If it was necessary to drop a column or rearrange the columns does each one of those actions require invoking a new dataframe? In "df1" I am able to combine two distinct actions, which include reading in all CSV files and concatenating them. I was unable to add additional actions but even so that line would eventually become difficult to read. Which approach have you adopted when working with dataframes that incorporated many smaller tasks? Thanks.

Comment: unless you need the preceding iterations df1, df2, just change all your df names to df1. Also, there's no reason you have to put all actions in one long line (maybe a performance issue??) Just doesn't seem to be a reason why you need to start new dataframe names

Comment: I usually override the variable value. In your case, once you reach to df3, you are really not referring to df1. so for each step, the assigned variable will be only df1. as "inplace=True" has memory issue, so this is only way going forward I feel.

Comment: @simpleApp Thanks. I assume that the structure would look something like this: `df1 = df1.sort_values(by='cmmac')` followed by `df1 = df1.drop_duplicates()`

Comment: yes, pls. That's correct.